# invert a curve by his x axis

Tags: c++, formula, curve

What would be the formula to rotate a curve by the x axis in java?

Comment: C++ or Java? Rotate around the x- or y-axis? What you show is flipped around the y-axis...

Comment: And what form is your curve in? A formula? An array of y-values? A table of x-y pairs?

Comment: I have two arrays: pointsX and pointsY

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a mathematical formula; not strictly a programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have the curve as an array of Points here is something like a pseudocode:

```
Point[] curve;

double x_max = curve[0].x, x_min = curve[0].x;
for( point : curve) {
  x_max = max(x_max, point.x);
  x_min = max(x_min, point.x);
}

for (point : curve) {
  point.x = x_max - point.x + x_min;
}
```

How does it work? In fact I try to mirror the curve's normalized coordinates - that is the coordinates that the points would have if they started from `x = 0` (the formula for that is `point.x - x_min`) and then you subtract the result from x_max so that the curve now is defined right to left instead of left to right.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not using vectors, just two arrays pointsX & pointsY. "max" is just the maximum of two values?

Comment: No max is the maximum value in PointX array. x_min is the minimum in the PointY array. Y coordinates of the points should stay intact.

Comment: I have adapted your code but it gives me strange result when I have more then two breakpoints in the curve.. Please see my original post. Thanks!

Comment: @menemenemu x_min depends again on the x coordinate not the y value! As I mentioned in my comment above y should stay intact so you shouldn't use it in the calculations. Try to understand the logic and it should become clear what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to know what this has to do with C++ or Java but mathematically, if you have a function `f(x)` that you want to flip along the x axis, you just do `f(-x)`.

Comment: Err, that would rather be `-f(x)` to flip around the x-axis, and `f(-x)` to flip around the y-axis

Comment: @AlexisPigeon "flip along" the x axis